# how to grant access to column that has mysql keyword

Tags: mysql, select

database name : testing ,
table name : mine , 
column name : primary ,
user : parwin

I am figuring out how to grant select access to parwin to that specific column called primary.

I can do it with backtick and it successful. but it caused my replica error.

I am trying to find solution without backtick.

Please help. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

> ... how to grant select access to ... column called primary.

The standard answer in these cases, as Michael Kutz has *quite rightly* said, is this:

> Don't use keywords for column names

*Why* do we say this?
Because it *inevitably* comes back and bites you in the ...   behind.

> I can do it with backtick and it successful. but it caused my replica error.

And there you go ...   bitten.

Save yourself further grief and *change* that column name.